# Сложить 3 строки, одна из них это математический знак(+, -, /, *) через js?

Tags: javascript

Вот такая задача, не могу решить ее, у меня происходит простая конкатенация строк, а мне нужно чтобы произошло математическое действие, помогите!

```js
function f14(){
let inputFirst = Number(document.querySelector(".i-141").value);
let inputSecond = Number(document.querySelector(".i-142").value);
let select = document.querySelector(".s-143").value;

document.querySelector(".out-14").innerHTML = inputFirst + select + inputSecond;
console.log(typeof inputFirst)
console.log(typeof inputSecond)
console.log(typeof select)
}

document.querySelector('.b-14').onclick = f14;
```

```html
<div>
<input type="number" class="i-141" value="8"></div>
<div><input type="number" class="i-142" value="7"></div>
            <div>
                <select class="s-143">
                    <option value="+">+</option>
                    <option value="-">-</option>
                    <option value="*">*</option>
                    <option value="/">/</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button class="button-primary b-14">Task-14</button>
            <div class="out-14"></div>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придётся в коде писать `switch/case` для каждого математического знака калькулятора, где происходит анализ знака и действие вручную в зависимости от него. Вот и весь секрет.

Comment: Оно спасибо, а то мне дали совет еще через eval(), но мне это странно показалось, а Ваш в точку, спасибо. вот так написал:

switch (select) {
   case '+': answer.innerHTML = inputFirst + inputSecond;
   break;
   case '-': answer.innerHTML = inputFirst + inputSecond;
   break;
   case '*': answer.innerHTML = inputFirst * inputSecond;
   break;
   case '/': answer.innerHTML = inputFirst / inputSecond;
   break;
}

Comment: ну eval тоже можно. тут много факторов влияет на выбор.....eval при неумелом подходе ведёт к уязвимому коду...но иногда применить можно))  вон, react так делает))

Comment: думаю мне как более начинающему, его лучше не трогать (eval), да и читал что опасная штука в руках не профи.  А вот switch/case то что надо. Спасибо за решение вопроса)

Answer (score 0):

Вышло 2 варианта кому интересно:

1)

```
switch (select) {
   case '+': answer.innerHTML = inputFirst + inputSecond;
   break;
   case '-': answer.innerHTML = inputFirst + inputSecond;
   break;
   case '*': answer.innerHTML = inputFirst * inputSecond;
   break;
   case '/': answer.innerHTML = inputFirst / inputSecond;
   break;
}
```

2. 

```
document.querySelector(".out-14").innerHTML = eval(inputFirst + select + inputSecond);
```